# How do I make a POST using X-HTTP-Method-Override with a PHP curl request?

Tags: php, curl, google-translate

I'm working with the Google Translate API and there's the possibility that I could be sending in quite a bit of text to be translated. In this scenerio Google recommends to do the following:

> You can also use POST to invoke the API if you want to send more data
>   in a single request. The q parameter in the POST body must be less
>   than 5K characters. To use POST, you must use the
>   X-HTTP-Method-Override header to tell the Translate API to treat the
>   request as a GET (use X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET). [Google Translate API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html)

I know how to make a normal POST request with CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

But how do I modify the header to use the X-HTTP-Method-Override?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET') );
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm still getting BAD REQUEST. ;(

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**
>
> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

Thus,

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option to add a header from a string array

Answer (score 0):

Not enough for me , i need to use http_build_query  fo my array post data
my full example :

```
  $param = array(
    'key'    => 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    'target' => 'en',
    'source' => 'fr',
    "q" => 'text to translate'
    );
    $formData = http_build_query($param);
    $headers = array( "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET");
    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$formData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://yoursite'); //if you have refere domain restriction for your google API KEY
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2');
    $query = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getInfo($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $data  = json_decode($query,true);

    if (!is_array($data) || !array_key_exists('data', $data)) {
     throw new Exception('Unable to find data key');
    }
    if (!array_key_exists('translations', $data['data'])) {
     throw new Exception('Unable to find translations key');
    }
    if (!is_array($data['data']['translations'])) {
     throw new Exception('Expected array for translations');
    }
    foreach ($data['data']['translations'] as $translation) {
     echo $translation['translatedText'];
    }
```

I found this help here https://phpfreelancedeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/translating-text-using-the-google-translate-api-and-php-json-and-curl/
Hope that helps